# mark both warning and error at the same field will shadow one of them

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I mark both warning and error at the same field.
The warning is `unquoted XXX name is case insensitive` and quickfix for that is `add double quote`. The error is `XXX doesn't exist in YYY` and quickfix for that is `change 'XXX' to 'ZZZ'`.

Although there is an error marker at that field. When I move over it, the message and quickfix are for warning. However both error and warning are succefully proposed since if I move to error icon on the left border line, I could see both error and warning. If I remove code to propose warning then I could see the correct error message. Can't I propose both error and warning at the same field?

[image]
[image]
[image]

The code I used to propose warning and error

```
warning("unquoted table name is case insensitive", 
  CqlPackage.Literals.TABLE_NAME__NAME, 
  CqlConstants.CASE_INSENSITIVE_NAME);

error(tableField.getName() + " table doesn't exist in keyspace " + ksMeta.getName(), 
  CqlPackage.Literals.TABLE_NAME__NAME, 
  CqlConstants.TABLE_NOT_EXIST, 
  tableField.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to suppress warnings on the user interface. However, you could restructure your code that it first looks for errors, and if no errors are found, only then will it look for warnings.

That behaviour is similar to most editor-based validations, and does not miss any real problem, however, would avoid the issues you mentioned.

Comment: That kind of class will appear in many places. I write a rule to check that class, therefore I only need to write once. To achieve your proposal, I need to write a rule for each field. (even if they will just make the same function call, still need to copy that function in many different places)